# How to access instance from outside?

Tags: openstack

I installed openstack using packstack. But I don't know how to configure network.

I want to access my instance using ssh like this.

[image]

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Packstack creates an "external" network that is entirely contained inside the host. This is great for creating a cloud without any knowledge of the network environment, but prevents you from accessing instances from outside.

Configure your Packstack so that its external network is your network. This is documented at https://www.rdoproject.org/networking/neutron-with-existing-external-network/.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, without external network its not possible.Your instance should have external(public) ip.I'm using this way but you have other option like proxy.

if your Centos7 machine can connect your instance;

Use HaProxy at Centos machine and proxy **instance** ssh port to specific **centos7** port and connect using this port.I'm using this way on microstack.